# Which RegExp matches a colon between two pairs of digits?

Tags: javascript, regex

Using `.match()`, `.replace()` and other RegExp-things I need to make the RegExp, which could change those example input strings:

```
'123'
'1234'
'qqxwdx1234sgvs'
'weavrt123adcsd'
```

to normal output ones:

```
'1:23'
'12:34'
```

(So, three-digit clusters must be x:xx formatted).

Comment: What should your code do for your other cases? Insert `:` anyway or not?

Comment: I think you'll need to provide more information about your requirements for where the colon should be placed in various cases. For example, should `123` become `1:23` or `12:3`? Do you want letters to be ignored or throw an error?

Comment: RegExps do not insert strings, tey **match** strings.

Comment: remember that Stackoverflow is about *specific* problems. Given an example is fine, but you're not describing what input you *have*, what it represents, and what you want to do with it, and what *that* represents. SO is not the right place to ask "what if the input is ...", that's a question we should be asking you, and you should already know the answer because you need something to happen to your input, and you know what that input looks like.

Comment: Sorry, guys. Editing question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with a regex that matches 1 or 2 digits followed by 2 digits. `$1` is the first captured group (1 or 2 digits), `$2` is the second captured group (2 digits). `$1:$2` is the replacement, it replaces the matched text with the first captured group (`$1`) followed by a colon (`:`), followed by the second captured group (`$2`).

```js
var string = '123';
string = string.replace(/^(\d{1,2})(\d{2})$/, '$1:$2');

console.log(string); // "1:23"
```

Explanation of the regex:

```
  ^                        the beginning of the string
  (                        group and capture to $1:
    \d{1,2}                  digits (0-9) (between 1 and 2 times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
  )                        end of $1
  (                        group and capture to $2:
    \d{2}                    digits (0-9) (2 times)
  )                        end of $2
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```